# Delete rows IF all cells in selected ROW is BLANK

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I have financial data where some rows are blank and id like to be able to delete the entire row IF entire rows in a selected range are blank (its important for it to be in selected range as I might have "Revenues" in column A but then I have column B-D be blank data (no numbers basically)).

I'd like for it to apply to a selected range, instead of having a predetermined range in the code (for the code to be flexible).

I am trying to use this format but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
Sub deleteBlankRows()
Dim c As Range

On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Selection.Row.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop trough each *complete* row of selection and check if the count of blank cells matchs the count of all cells in row:

[image]

My code:

```
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Selection.Rows
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) = rng.Cells.Count Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
Next rng
```

After executing code:

[image]

The emtpy row is gone

**UPDATE:**

@VasilyIvoyzha is absolutely right. `For each` won't work properly on this situation. A better approach would be:

```
Dim i&, x&, lastRow&
lastRow = Range(Split(Selection.Address, ":")(1)).Row
x = Selection.Rows.Count
For i = lastRow To Selection.Cells(1).Row Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.Concat(Selection.Rows(x)) = "" Then Rows(i).Delete
    x = x - 1
Next i
```

This way will delete empty rows on selection, even if they are consecutive.

Comment: if the row are empty one after another, the second will not be deleted, plus 1 in advance from my side but it will be better to change `for each` to `for` with `step -1`

Comment: @VasilyIvoyzha You are right. Updated the code. Thanks!

Comment: HI guys, thank you for the feebdack, i did notice the same as @VasilyIvoyzha with the first code, with the second one --------- Dim i&, lastRow&

lastRow = Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

For i = lastRow To Selection.Cells(1).Row Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.Concat(Rows(i)) = "" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i End Sub ' ---------It doesnt seem to work at all (im selecting range c1:f5) could it be because I have text in column A ? (Sorry dont know how to post the code in comments)

Comment: @JROB thought the whole row is empty, see update